# Flush Windows batch file outputs to log file

Tags: batch-file

When I run some app from  command line in Windows (11 if that matters) which outputs to a log using

`>> some_app.exe param1 > log.txt`

the log file is kept empty until the app finishes running which is exactly what I don't want since I want to track the printed messages once they are printed by it instead of getting one bulk at the end.

Is there a way to flush the outputs every period of time?

Comment: You need to run your app in another instance: `start "pinging" cmd /c "ping -t localhost >x.txt"`. Regularly do `type x.txt` in the original window and watch the file grow.

Comment: @RomeoNinov No, I need a command line example relative to my code

Comment: `start "some title" cmd /c "some_app.exe param1 > log.txt"`

Comment: @Stephan No, it doesn't work